# How is vocal fry used in singing?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, vocal-fry

I only came across this term recently. Wikipedia explains what it is quite well (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register) and I came across this introductory video which uses it as an exercise (http://www.aussievocalcoach.com/2009/08/21/how-to-sing-vocal-fry/)

However I'm still not really sure of the point. Is it a register people use to extend their range downwards, or is it used as an exercise which will aid your normal singing range/tone? Because it doesn't sound very good to me!

What place does vocal fry have in vocal training and/or singing for a typical singer?

Comment: I have a friend who was a bass in his college glee club and they discussed vocal fry. I believe he was told not to use it since it was believed to be bad for one's voice. I'm not sure about the truth of that or not, but it at least seems like it is not universally regarded as a valid technique.

Comment: My main issue with it is that in it's pure form, it just sounds plain awful. Maybe it's useful just for warm-up, I've seen it recommended for that, or for extreme low notes i.e. not stuff I ever need!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it may have a place in combination with microphone technique and a well-controlled bass voice.  Cf the ["Wayfaring Stranger" rendition of JD Sumner and the Stamps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu_wW4OJwjY), the partial-fry parts being after the 3 minute mark.  Not that he is singing exactly at high pitch before that.

Comment: This kind of sounds like [Tom Waits' normal voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wfamPW3Eaw)

Answer (score 1):

Vocal fry doesn't have much of a place in most singing traditions. Contemporary music sometimes calls for it as an extended technique, but even then it's only used very sparingly. There are several reasons for this: it doesn't project well without amplification, the sound is extremely difficult to control, and it isn't healthy for the voice.